# Vuejs $emit doesn't fire on callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

In the following code:

```
export default {
    props: ['note'],
    methods: {
        remove(){
            NoteRepo.remove(this.note, (err) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('Should Fire')
                    this.$emit('alerted', {
                        type: 'error', 
                        message: 'Failed to remove note'
                    });
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

When the remove function gets called, the console logs "Should Fire" but the $emit event doesn't get fired. If I move the $emit outside of the callback like so:

```
export default {
    props: ['note'],
    methods: {
        remove(){
            this.$emit('alerted', {
                type: 'error', 
                message: 'Failed to remove note'
            });

            NoteRepo.remove(this.note, (err) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('Should Fire')
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

It works. I've tried assigning `_this = this` and using that to fire the $emit but no difference.

Why does the $emit event not fire in a callback?

Comment: have you tried not using an arrow function? I just started using vue but I seem to remember reading in the docs that arrow functions don't bind context properly when used in some places.

Comment: Yeah, if I understand correctly, when using arrow function `this` represents the Vue instance, so in this case an arrow function is fine. That being said, I have tried (and also assigning `_self = this` in the process) and there's no difference. I've tried all sorts of ways to alias it but no luck.

Comment: I found the relevant bit here: http://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Properties-and-Methods looks like arrow function isn't binding to the vm instance.

Comment: what @theWanderer4865 suggest is correct. To resolve your issue, emit the event directly and let that event handler handle NoteRepo.remove().

Comment: But it's on the callback I need to emit the event. When the callback fails and responds with an error, I need to tell the alerts component to show a fail error. Or am I not following? If so, could you perhaps give me a code example?

Comment: I should also mention that in the callback (arrow or when reassigned to _self in a normal function) `this` refers to the Vue instance.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out it was something in NoteRepo causing the problem. Specifically the firebase event callback.

```
constructor () {
        super();

        // Initialize Firebase
        Firebase.initializeApp({
            apiKey: "xxx",
            authDomain: "xxx",
            databaseURL: "xxx",
            storageBucket: "xxx",
            messagingSenderId: "xxx"
        });

        this.ref = Firebase.database().ref('notes');
        this.attachFirebaseListeners();
    }

    attachFirebaseListeners() {
        this.ref.on('child_added', this.onAdded, this);
        this.ref.on('child_removed', this.onRemoved); // Removing 'this' here seems to of fixed it.
        this.ref.on('child_changed', this.onChanged, this);
    }
```

I'm not sure what exactly was wrong, but this seems to of sorted it for now.