# Vuejs $emit didn't trigger parent's function on callback

Tags: javascript, callback, vue.js, superagent, emit

My question is just like this one:[Vuejs $emit doesn't fire on callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40451053/vuejs-emit-doesnt-fire-on-callback).
But I used the superagent in my project. Here is my code:

```
//Parent.vue
<Child v-on:savevideo="toSaveVideo"/>
...
methods:{
  toSaveVideo:function(data){
    console.log('add');
  }
}

//Child.vue
<button @click="toAdd">Add</button>
...
methods:{
  toAdd:function(){
    ...
    let self = this;
    superagent
      .get(url)
      .query({data:data})
      .end(function(err,res){
        //trigger parent function
        let resData = res.body.data;
        self.$emit('savevideo',resData);
    })
  }
}
```

The request is successful but when trigger 'savevideo', the method 'toSaveVideo' in parent didn't print anything. However, when I put the emit outside the callback, everything is fine.
Why does the $emit event not fire in a callback?

Answer (score 0):

ok, I figured it out.

**'v-if' is bound on the child component.**

Because in my project, in the child component, there is another trigger 'close' to close this child component, and it was emitted outside the callback, and this caused the problem.

```
//Parent.vue
<Child v-on:savevideo="toSaveVideo" v-if="showChild" v-on:close="toClose"/>
...
methods:{
  toClose:function(){
    this.showChild = false;
  }
}

//Child.vue
<button @click="toAdd">Add</button>
...
methods:{
  toAdd:function(){
    ...
    let self = this;
    superagent
      .get(url)
      .query({data:data})
      .end(function(err,res){
        //trigger parent function
        let resData = res.body.data;
        self.$emit('savevideo',resData);
        //'close' should be emitted here!
    })
    this.$emit('close'); //bad code!! This cause the problem!
  }
}
```